# Cannot call value of non-function type 'Bool'

Tags: swift

The code below does not compile

> Cannot call value of non-function type 'Bool'

Is is possible to distinguish between a method closure argument and local variable when both have the same name?

```
func methodA(message: String, success: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let success = true
    if success {
        print(message)
    }
    success()
}
```

Comment: No way to distinguish. Give another name.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that because all the vars you pass to the function are function's vars, so there is no way to distinguish between success function to success var.

More swift way is to change the name to completion and return a bool var indicate success or fail like that:

```
func methodA(message: String, completion: @escaping (_ success: Bool) -> Void) {
    let success = true
    if success {
        print(message)
    }
    completion(success)
}
```

Comment: `completion` with an "e" seems better ;)